# How to set focus on specific input?

Tags: angular

So i have loop where i have list of inputs. I have directive for focus but i want to add focus on specific input. This is my plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/POP7Fh6G2bWhBEPBkTSm?p=preview

```
 <div *ngFor="let input of inputs">
      <input type="text" focusOnInit>
    </div>
  inputs  = [
    {name:'Superman'},
    {name:'Batman'},
    {name:'BatGirl'},
    {name:'Robin'},
    {name:'Flash'}
];
```

Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: Which input is the specific input? When do you want to set the focus?

Comment: can i pass value every time?

Comment: What is "every time"? Please be more specific about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I have dropdown and on every dropdown change i have different list of inputs. So i want on to change dropdown to set focus on different inputs. For example if i choose from dropdown first i will set focus on first, but when i choose second value from dropdown i want to set focus on third input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```ts
@Input()
focusOnInit:number;
```

and

```ts
focus() {
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
    this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
}
```

to the `focusOnInit` directive and then pass an id like

```ts
[focusOnInit]="input.id"
```

In the parent component you can query all `focusOnInit` directives

```ts
@ViewChildren(FocusOnInit) focusDirectives: FocusOnInit[];
```

when you want to set the focus on a specific input use

```ts
focus(id) {
  var input = this.focusDirectives.toArray().find((f) => f.focusOnInit === id);
  if(input) {
    input.focus();
  }
}
```